# How works gzip_types image/jpeg

Tags: nginx, gzip

I now and always use gzip with nginx but never use it for images. Try to find some adventages/disadventages of that kind solution but nothing found.

Of course I can use client side caching in nginx and set expired days for images - but then first load will be always full load without any optimization.

Soo should I or shouldnt gzip images jpeg png etc. ? What this type of commpresion do - change commpression of images to lower quality?

Comment: GZip is unlikely to compress images further and may make the file larger if it isn't smart enough to ignore that file type, due to additional header information.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't compress images because images are already compressed. In some cases it can actually make them larger (but I've forgotten the reason why). These are binary formats, similar to videos and you won't gain any benefit.

Comment: Ok soo only I can download smaller/more compressed images

Comment: ps. or RoR I have nice page caching or even partial caching ... must search for something like this in php